# XML CDATA Encoding

Tags: c#, xml, cdata

I know to use `CreateCDataSection` to generate a CDATA node. However, is there any way to insert a CDATA string into my original string? Instead of having the whole node being enclosed by CDATA tag. Below is my code. Please advise, thanks.

```
var detail = new StringBuilder();
detail.AppendFormat("<![CDATA[<br />]]>another line: {0}", foo1);
detail.AppendFormat("<![CDATA[<br />]]>another line: {0}", foo2);
detail.AppendFormat("<![CDATA[<br />]]>another line: {0}", foo3);

var xmlOutput = new XElement("Detail",detail);
```

Comment: Can you explain the question in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CDATA, use `&lt;` for the '<'.

```
detail.AppendFormat("&lt;br />another line: {0}", foo1);
detail.AppendFormat("&lt;br />another line: {0}", foo2);
detail.AppendFormat("&lt;br />another line: {0}", foo3);

var xmlOutput = new XElement("Detail", detail);
```

Comment: I need to enclose <br/> with CDATA so that it will work with the API my program interactive with.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this.

```
        var br = new XCData("<br />");
        detail.AppendFormat("{0}another line: {1}", br, foo1);
        detail.AppendFormat("{0}another line: {1}", br, foo2);
        detail.AppendFormat("{0}another line: {1}", br, foo3);            
        var xmlOutput = new XElement("Detail", detail);
```